# Python: Error while making foolproof input method using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, input

```
digits = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']

def inp():
    inp = input('Enter a value: ')

    for i in inp:
        if i not in digits:
            print('Please enter a value from 2 to 100')
            inp()

    n = int(inp)
    if not 2 <= n <= 100:
        print('Please enter a value from 2 to 100')
        inp()
    else:
        return n

number = inp()
```

I am unable to make it foolproof: user can enter an empty string `""` or float, and it gives an error.

For example: If I enter `10.5` and then `10` then it shows error that 10.5 cannot be taken as integral value.

If there would be a simple function like `val()` from VB6 or something equivalent for python, I would be very grateful.

Edit: Expected behaviour:
I want the code to take only integral value, 2 to 100 as input, and if incorrect value is entered then it should repeat until an appropriate value is received.

Please help.

Comment: I have to re-ask since https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69658320/error-while-making-foolproof-input-method-using-for-loop was closed and my problem was not solved.

Comment: What is the purpose of the full-proof test? Please describe the expected behavior (or your question might be closed again)

Comment: you can do: `try int(input)`, did you try that?

Comment: Also, avoid the recursive approach, an infinite loop with a break on condition is much better

Comment: "infinite loop with a break on condition" --- I am unaware of that, fellow coder
Are you referring to "while True break"??

Comment: the main problem is solved. anyways, is there an val() equivalent function from VB6 in Python, or in some library i can import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to be this:

```
def inp_w():
    while True:
        try:
            inp = round(float(input('Width of the maze (number of blocks): ')))
        except:
            print('Please enter a value from 2 to 100')
            continue
        else:
            break
    
    if not 2 <= inp <= 100:
        print('Please enter a value from 2 to 100')
        inp_w()
    else:
        return inp


a = inp_w()
```

```
Thanks to
"https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway"
"https://stackoverflow.com/users/13000953/mahrkeenerh"
"https://stackoverflow.com/users/9635106/karl-wilhelm"
"https://stackoverflow.com/users/16601101/jeandemeusy"
```

Answer (score -1):

There is three errors you are making:

- you named a method and a variable the same way. The interpreter doesn't know what to do when it comes to "inp()". Are you trying to call method "inp" or the variable "inp" ? One of them is impossible to do, so it crashes. As y good practice, never give the same name to different element in your code.
- you are missing the character '.' in your list of digits. When parsing the string "10.5" it doesn't recognizes the dot, and thus crashes.
- the conversion from string to int is not able to convert "10.5" to 10, because of the floating point part. So convert it to a float instead of an int.

Here is a working code:

```
valid_chars = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "."]


def input_val():
    inp = input("Enter a value: ")

    for i in inp:
        if i not in valid_chars:
            print("Please enter a value from 2 to 100")
            return input_val()

    n = float(inp)
    if not 2 <= n <= 100:
        print("Please enter a value from 2 to 100")
        return input_val()

    return n


number = input_val()
```

Edit: A better answer, without recursion could be something like this:

```
def is_float(string):
    try:
        float(string)
        return True
    except:
        return False


def input_val(min_val: int, max_val: int):

    while True:
        inp = input("Enter a value: ")

        if not is_float(inp):
            print("Please enter a number")
        else:
            n = float(inp)
            if not min_val <= n <= max_val:
                print(f"Please enter a value from {min_val} to {max_val}")
            else:
                break
    return n


number = input_val(2, 100)
```

Comment: And what for an empty string "" ? It still gives an error when I pass a condition for the same and seems to save the value from last iteration even after taking input.

Comment: Just add a condition after the input. something like "if len(inp) == 0: print("error") return input_val()"

Comment: Recursion is not a good idea to solve this problem.

Comment: I know, but I kept his structure to make his code work. Personally I would have used a while loop with a flag to break out.